# How to convert Django source installation to package like installation

Tags: python, django

OS : CentOS, Redhat

New to Django and python, we basically built a monitoring tool using python and Django framework. Below is the project folder structure.

```
|-- Makefile
|-- monitor-pycodes
`-- web
    |-- content
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- manage.py
    |-- monitor_templ
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- templates
    |   |-- templatetags
    |   |-- urls.py
    |   `-- views.py
    |-- packmonitor.wsgi
    |-- settings.py
    `-- urls.py
```

Didnt mentioned the certain folders content to simplify the view.

We used **Makefile** to copy our codes to system folders as below

All python codes in "monitor-pycodes" --> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packmonitor/ and compile it

Django templates in "web" --> /var/www/packmonitor for web UI.

scritps such as packmontior & packmonitord to --> /usr/bin

When run **make install** inside the project directory, above copying process take place and application started.

My employer doesnt want this tool to be install from source.

How to convert this install from source to package installation ?

Thanks,
Mohan

Answer (score 2):

Django is a Python Package that is typically downloaded and installed from PyPI into a virtual environment using a tool like `virtualenv`, or in Python 3.3+, `venv`, which is packaged with Python. You may also have some other dependencies, for example, a Python package for communication with a database.

You can create a virtual environment within your directory structure and do the installations. As long as you're creating the virtual environment on the same OS as you are deploying to, you will likely be able to include the virtual environment of packages as part of your payload for deployment. For example, I use Vagrant with CentOS 7.6 for development, and my production servers run RHEL 7.6. I make sure that any underlying requirements installed by `yum` are the same on Vagrant for development as they are on my production servers.

This would allow you to point the `.wsgi` file to the virtual environment that you deploy along with the rest of your code.

Just a few things to consider, however; this goes against most documented best practices for deployment. You also mention you're running Python 2.7; support for Python 2.7 ends in several months. It will also restrict you to running Django 1.11, which will only have support for several months as well. That means no more security updates or bug fixes. Django 2.0 supports only Python 3.4 and above.

If you're taking the time to deploy, it may be worth considering an upgrade to Python 3.7 and Django 2.2 (a long term support release, guaranteed to have three years of security updates). The deployment method I've described above, with a virtual environment as part of your payload, should work with the new versions of Python and Django. Upgrading will take a little bit of work now, but potentially save you a truck load of pain down the road, by paying down some technical debt as maintenance before it becomes a crisis.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to  convert to  python3. Is vagarant package the tool similar to how rpm does? Thanks

Comment: Vagrant is a tool to build VMs, typically for developing locally on a laptop and mimicking a production environment. So it's a very different tool than `rpm`. https://www.vagrantup.com/